# WP All Import Selecting Image ID

Tags: php, wordpress, image, file-upload

New to the more intricate things of WordPress, Imports, and Mods - so if it is a dumb question, please be patient :)

As you can see below - I have mapped out the fields, however, in the properties layout, there is a Gallery option to add more images of the property - however, I cannot add the URL to the Field as seen below - as then the images are not added to the Gallery.

The Gallery needs the Image ID in order for it to be added to the Gallery.

How do I map the ID of the Images that I have downloaded from the URL, to the ImageID on my WordPress installation?

Thanks in advance!!

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure there is a direct way to do this; you might need to write this yourself using either custom PHP code in the import, https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/, or via their AddOn API. https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/addon-dev/image-fields/

Comment: @CBroe - Thank you - seeing the hooks - I think there is something there that I can work with, but my PHP is not up to that level, so will have to try and do a lot of trial and error - thank you again!